# how to create bundle product in Magento 2 by REST API?

Tags: magento2

I want to create a bundle product through REST API in postman client, but i can't seem to find the right API to create the same. I can add bundle options through REST API but to add those options i need to have a bundle product.So can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issue trying to create a bundle product with the Magento 2 API but finally figured it out, as this post come up every time I googled I will answer here with the request you need to make through postman in order to create a bundle product. Using the url http://{{host}}/rest/default/V1/products with method POST and the Authorization header with the token received from http://{{host}}/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token, you will have to send the following body as JSON in order to create a bundle product with associated products:

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "some-bundle-sku",
    "name": null,
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 1000,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 1,
    "type_id": "bundle",
    "created_at": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
        "qty": 100
      },
      "website_ids": [
        1
      ],
      "category_links": [],
      "bundle_product_options": [
        {
          "option_id": 0,
          "position": 1,
          "sku": "bundle-option-sku",
          "title": "Bundle products",
          "type": "select",
          "required": true,
          "product_links": [
            {
              "sku": "some prod 1 sku",
              "option_id": 1,
              "qty": 1,
              "position": 1,
              "is_default": false,
              "price": null,
              "price_type": null,
              "can_change_quantity": 0
            },
            {
              "sku": "some prod 2 sku",
              "option_id": 1,
              "qty": 1,
              "position": 2,
              "is_default": false,
              "price": null,
              "price_type": null,
              "can_change_quantity": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "price_view",
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}
```

Make sure that the products you are adding in "product_links" exist otherwise it will not create the bundle product. Pay attention to "bundle_product_options", this needs to be an array of options, my mistake was that I was trying to create a single option and I was not passing it within an array.

Answer (score 0):

To Create Bundle Product in Magento 2 via REST API:

```
//API URL for authentication

$apiURL="http://{host}/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";

//parameters passing with URL

$data = array("username" => "<username>", "password" => "<password>");  

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($apiURL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

//decoding generated token and saving it in a variable

$token =  json_decode($token);

print_r($token);

//Using above token into header

$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer ".$token);

//API URL to Add Product(s) in Magento

$requestUrl='http://{host}/rest/default/V1/products';

$toBeAdded = '{
  "product": {
    "sku": "some-bundle-sku",
    "name": Demo-Bundle,
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 1000,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 1,
    "type_id": "bundle",
    "created_at": "2019-04-28 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-28 00:00:00",
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
        "qty": 100
      },
      "website_ids": [
        1
      ],
      "category_links": [],
      "bundle_product_options": [
        {
          "option_id": 0,
          "position": 1,
          "sku": "bundle-option-sku",
          "title": "Bundle products",
          "type": "select",
          "required": true,
          "product_links": [
            {
              "sku": "Sample",
              "option_id": 1,
              "qty": 1,
              "position": 1,
              "is_default": false,
              "price": 20,
              "price_type": null,
              "can_change_quantity": 0
            },
            {
              "sku": "Demo",
              "option_id": 1,
              "qty": 1,
              "position": 2,
              "is_default": false,
              "price": 30,
              "price_type": null,
              "can_change_quantity": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "price_view",
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveOptions": true
}';

$ch = curl_init();
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$toBeAdded
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result=  json_decode($result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

This should resolve your issues. Also make sure Assigned User has Access to desired Resources and the product you are adding as bundle options must exit on your Magento  environment.

Happy coding ! Cheers !

Answer (score -1):

To create bundle product in Magento 2 by REST API, We will be followed some step's see below:

**STEP 1-** First let us write the configurations (URL's,username,password)

// configuration Data

```
$url="http://www.example.com/index.php/";
$token_url=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
$product_url=$url. "rest/V1/products";
$username="your admin username";
$password="your admin password";

$product_links = array(
                        array("sku"=>"cpu1","qty"=>1)
                    );
```

**STEP 2-** Then let us get access token

//Authentication rest API magento2, get access token

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken=  json_decode($token);
```

**STEP 3-** No let us prepare the Product data

// Create the Configurable Product

```
$configProductData = array(

        'sku'               => 'bundle'. uniqid(),
        'name'              => 'Bundle' . uniqid(),
        'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
        'type_id'           => 'bundle',
        'price'             => 99.95,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["42","41","32"] ),
                array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Description' ),
                array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Short Description' ),
                array( 'attribute_code' => 'price_view', 'value' => '0' ),
                array( 'attribute_code' => 'price_type', 'value' => '0' ),
        ),
        'extension_attributes' => array("bundle_product_options"=>array(
            array("title"=>"CPU","type"=>"select","product_links"=>$product_links),
        ),
        )
);
$productData = json_encode(array('product' => $configProductData));
```

**STEP 4-** At the end we will send the product data to magento to create the product

```
$setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```